# How to import a table containing arrays into PostgreSQL with pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a table which has data type "array". I've imported the data into pgAdmin4, but it always fails because I'm confused about how to import data that has an array data type. Below is the code that I have tried

```
CREATE TABLE dvdrentals.film (
film_id smallint,
title varchar,
description text,
release_year int,
language_id smallint,
original_language_id smallint,
rental_duration smallint,
rental_rate numeric,
length smallint,
replacement_cost numeric,
rating varchar,
last_update timestamp,
special_features varchar[]);
```

how to import special_features column with array data type?

Contents of the data type array:

```
special_features
["Deleted Scenes","Behind the Scenes"]
["Trailers","Deleted Scenes","Behind the Scenes"]
...
```

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what you mean by "import". Do you want `INSERT` statements? Do you want to `COPY` the data?

Comment: in pgadmin 4 you can see when you right click there are many options and it says "import/export data".

Comment: I see. I have adjusted the question to make clear that you are asking about pgAdmin functionality.

Comment: Where did the data come from in the first place?  That data looks more like JSON than text[].